# Pygame struggling to make object appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I'm trying to familiarise myself with Python and am trying to make an "alien invaders" style game using Pygame. I'm able to import an image of a ship and move it left and right.

Now I'm trying to the ship to fire a bullet whenever the space bar is pressed, but when I press it nothing happens.

This is my main program that trigger the behaviour on a key press:

```
while run:
  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    #calls a function that increments the x coordinate of the ship
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        ship.updateRight()
    #calls a function that decrements the x coordinate of the ship    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        ship.updateLeft()
    #calls a function that updates the screen to create a bullet  
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)
    
    bullets.update()                
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

When the space bar is pressed the following functions from the Bullet class are called:

```
class Bullet(Sprite):
    
    def __init__ (self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        
        #create bullet rect (0,0) and then set the correct position
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
        
        #store the bullet's position as a decimal value
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        
        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor
        
    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet up the screen"""
        #update the decimal position of the bullet 
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y
        
    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Draw the bullet to the screen."""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)'''
```

and finally the "update_screen" function called in the main loop (it includes some other updates for the ship):

```
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
   screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
   #ship.blitme()
   pygame.display.flip()
   for bullet in bullets.sprites():
       bullet.draw_bullet()
```

If anyone has any ideas as to why a bullet is not appearing please help! Haven't been able to figure this one out yet as I'm still very new to Python.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `pygame.display.flip()` has to be done after `for bullet in bullets.sprites():` `bullet.draw_bullet()`

Comment: maybe provide some more code

Comment: @Mattiss No it is not. Did you try? WE DO Not guess here.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76) said, `pygame.display.flip()` has to be done **after** the `for bullet in bullets.sprites(): bullet.draw_bullet`

The reason is that when you "update" the screen, everything's that been drawn so far will be put onto the screen. Simple, right?
When you put something AFTER the `pygame.display.flip()`, it will not draw it the time it is run. Plus, when you refill the screen with `ai_settings.bg_color`, after you drew the bullets, they're all covered up by the new screen you filled. So, it never shows up.

So, `update_screen()` needs to be:

```
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
   screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
   #ship.blitme()
   for bullet in bullets.sprites():
       bullet.draw_bullet()
   pygame.display.flip()
```